# Exported Excel file from GridView not able to import again to GridView using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I have .aspx page which contains `GridView` and asp.net button to export the `GridView` to Excel. All works fine. Just the thing is when i export the `GridView` to `Excel`(.xls) all rows gets exported.

The `Excel` file contains prices of products. These prices are `Updated` by user and later on `Uploaded` to `GridView` and accordingly the prices of the products are updated in to the DataBase.

When i try to upload the `Exported Excel(.xls)` to `GridView` it says '**ERROR: External table is not in the expected format**'. But when the same file is saved with option 'SAVE AS' it works fine.

Any suggestions?

**Export GridView to Excel(.xls)**

```
protected void btnExportEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView2.AllowSorting = false;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TeraPeakDevicePrices_Edit.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        //Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
        new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);


        GridView2.DataSourceID = sqlUsers.ID;//sqlDevicePriceListExport.ID;
        GridView2.DataBind();

        StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter); GridView2.RenderControl(hWriter);
        string style = @"<style> .textmode {mso-number-format:General} </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Write(sWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush(); Response.End();


    }
```

**Upload Exported Excel(.xls) to GridView.**

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
protected void btnUploadOLD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fupCSV.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbConnection objConn = null;
                string fileSavePath = "";
                fileSavePath = CommonFunc.GetFileName(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/" + "UploadedFiles"), fupCSV.FileName));
                fupCSV.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
                hdnFileUploaded.Value = fileSavePath;
                var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileSavePath);
                objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                objConn.Open();
                DataTable columndt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                String[] excelSheets = new String[columndt.Rows.Count];
                if (columndt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    // Add the sheet name to the string array.
                    foreach (DataRow row in columndt.Rows)
                    {
                        excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        i++;
                    }
                }

               // var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheets[0] + "] where [Sales Record Number] is not null", connectionString);
                //SMS:
                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheets[0] + "] ", connectionString);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                objConn.Close();
                adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere");

                DataTable data = ds.Tables["anyNameHere"];
                if (data != null && data.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    btnUpdateChanges.Visible = true;
                }
                else {
                    btnUpdateChanges.Visible = false;
                }

                gvExcelFile.DataSource = data.DefaultView.ToTable();
                gvExcelFile.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Help Appreciated!

Comment: Try this http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2015/03/excel-file-upload-or-import-and-display.html

Comment: hi @PradnyaBolli i need to upload the Exported file without saving it again using 'Save As'. Importing fresh excel file works fine. any suggestions?

Comment: are you getting any error ?